# Contract.Requires and DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, code-contracts

I have the following method:

```
private static void SampleMethod(DateTime dateTime1, DateTime dateTime2)
{
    Contract.Requires(dateTime1 > dateTime2);
    Console.WriteLine("date 1 > date 2");
}

SampleMethod(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
```

When I build it with static checking enabled, I get the warning `CodeContracts: requires unproven: dateTime1 > dateTime2`

Note that dynamic checking is working fine for me, its only the static checking I'm having a problem with.

How do I go about either proving this assertion, or else suppressing the warning?

*EDIT:*

I was reading about the [ContractVerificationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contractverificationattribute.aspx), if I add `[ContractVefirication(false)` to the method it makes no difference (I suspect this might be a bug) but adding it to the class will turn off static checking correctly for the whole class.  Am still looking for a way to turn off static checking for that one Requires though.

Comment: You're showing us the code that contains the contract. Surely that message is arising from the *calling* code - which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Fair point, I have added a sample call to the method.  The warning is the same no matter how the method is called, so long as it IS called.

Comment: Your sample _is_ failing the contract, I'll insert a '-' .

Comment: The sample should fail the contract, I would like the code above to either fail statically or else not raise any compiler warning and fail dynamically instead.

Comment: Re Edit: The  ContractVerification should be applied to the _calling_ class or method. Adding it to SampleMethod() doesn't help. But this attribute is a white flag, saying you're giving up on Contracts.

Comment: Thanks for that Henk, that makes sense now.  I might just put the ContractVerificationAttribute on my test class and use the Contract.Assume in the real code, its much clearer than when I started looking at it anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static verifier has its limitations, sometimes you have to help. It has a limited understanding of numerical math but DateTime seems to be out of its scope.

That's why `Contract.Assume(bool)` exists:

```
    DateTime d1 = DateTime.Today;  
    DateTime d2 = d1.AddDays(-7);

    Contract.Assume(d1 > d2);

    SampleMethod(d1, d2);
```

> CodeContracts: Checked 4 assertions: 4 correct

Comment: +1 Thanks Henk, that works, I just need to find a way now to avoid having to precede every call to the method with Contract.Assume, as it makes it too unwieldy to test

Comment: Doesn’t that defeat the purpose of static contracts checking? Might as well just put a runtime assertion inside the method.

Comment: @Patrick, @timwi: Like I said, it's a limitation of the verifier. The Requires already functions as a runtime assertion, the trouble is indeed the callsites. Note that with `int` parameters this generally works.

Comment: I've noticed that its easy to work around while using ints, I'm beginning to suspect that it might be much easier to just go back to throwing ArgumentExceptions rather than using contracts on DateTime parameters.